# Maps.app is not opening programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude, coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

I am trying open Maps application on iPhone from my application to show direction between two location. But, it is showing written directions in safari from google rather than opening maps application. Can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** launch other apps from your app. However, maps should respond to the **http://maps.google.com** schema. Typically, **http://maps.google.com/** should launch the Maps application but I'm not sure why it is not.

Maps also supports **`maps://`** and **`mapitem://`** URL Schemes.

### Update

The iOS Simulator does not have the **Maps** app, so obviously this isn't going to work in the simulator. Works as expected on a physical device though.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i had read we couldn't launch other apps, guess it was referring to apps that weren't preinstalled. May i suggest you edit your answer to test in on actual device, as simulator will just open it in safari, as in case of OP.

Comment: @iNoob the question says this user is trying from their **iPhone**. But I updated my answer if they are trying it on the simulator.

Comment: that's true. But suggested just as a heads up. Thanks for update.

Comment: Thanks. maps://URL Scheme works. mapitem:// URL Schemes open maps but did not show the route. However, maps:// worked well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Avigit be sure to tick the checkmark. Glad it worked for you!